# Dask dataframe concat changes column type from 'int' to 'float'

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I work with large data time-series datasets. The data is stored in parquet files. Over time, new columns are added. I use concat to join data from the different files, which works really well, but I have run into a small' ish issue where the datatypes are not stable when concatenating dask data frames. Example:

I have two data frames with a different set of columns with both floats and integer datatypes:

```
import pandas as pd 
import dask.dataframe as dd

x = pd.DataFrame( [[1., 2.],[3., 4.]], columns=["a", "b"], index=[1,3])
y = pd.DataFrame( [[5., 6., 7], [8.,9., 10]], columns=["a", "b", "c"], index=[5,8])
```

dtypes on dataframe 'y' is **'float64', 'float64', 'int64'**.

If I convert a and b to dask dataframes and contatenate:

```
ddfs = [ dd.from_pandas( a, npartitions=1 ), dd.from_pandas( b, npartitions=1 ) ]
z = dd.concat(ddfs, axis=0)
```

dtypes on dataframe 'z' is '**float64', 'float64', 'float64'**, so the dtype of column 'c' changes from int to float when concatenating. The data is otherwise correct.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a surprise. Before pandas 1.0 it was not possible to have NaN on an integers series (see [whats_new](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html)). If you try to do `pd.concat([x,y]).info()` you'll see the very same output. So no it's not a bug it directly depends on how pandas works.